# Why voltage at AREF is given by Vin * R2 / Rtotal

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread

In [chapter 4](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nostarch.com%2Fdownload%2Fsamples%2FArduinows_ch4.pdf) of Arduino Workshop on page 85 (or page 31 in the pdf) it says that the voltage at AREF in the schematic is given by:

Vin * R2 / (R2 + R1)

However, the voltage is flowing from 5V to Ground so isn't AREF actually in parallel with R1, and so shouldn't AREF be given by:

Vin * R1 / (R1 + R2) ?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct.

$$V_{ref} = \dfrac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} \cdot V_{CC}$$

or Vref = Vin * R1 / (R1 + R2) until we finally get [MathJax](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-there-an-easy-way-to-enter-formulas-in-questions) enabled on this site.